# Pandas boolean statements to clean up dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with some messy EPA data that needs to be cleaned up. It looks like this:

```
id   1   value1   2    value2   3   value3
1    ph    7     temp   44     cond  3
2    temp  45    cond   5      ph    5    
3    temp  12    ph     5      cond    8
```

I would like to make new columns `ph`, `temp`, `alk`, `cond`, etc. while maintaining every value corresponding to the column in the row. Expected output would look something like this:

```
id   ph   temp   cond
1    7    44     3
2    5    45     5   
3    5    12     8
```

Comment: Expected output?

Comment: look at `pandas.pivot`. if you can't get it in one go, get a column/value for each of your columns and then left join them all together

Answer (score 1):

Let's try:

```
df1 = df.set_index('id')

df1.columns = ['Col'+i if i.isdigit() else i for i in df1.columns]

df2 = df1.reset_index()
pd.wide_to_long(df2, ['Col','value'],'id','num','','.+').reset_index(level=1, drop=True).set_index('Col', append=True)['value'].unstack()
```

Output:

```
Col  cond  ph  temp
id                 
1       3   7    44
2       5   5    45
3       8   5    12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# Initialize example input dataframe
col_names = ['id', '1', 'value1', '2', 'value2', '3', 'value3']
data = [
    [1, 'ph', 7, 'temp', 44, 'cond', 3],
    [2, 'temp', 45, 'cond', 5, 'ph', 5],
    [3, 'temp', 12, 'ph', 5, 'cond', 8],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col_names)

# Reshape dataframe
df2 = pd.concat([
    df[['id', '1', 'value1']].rename(columns={'1': 'parameter', 'value1': 'value'}),
    df[['id', '2', 'value2']].rename(columns={'2': 'parameter', 'value2': 'value'}),
    df[['id', '3', 'value3']].rename(columns={'3': 'parameter', 'value3': 'value'}),
])
df2 = df2.pivot(index='id', columns='parameter', values='value')
```

gives as result:

```
In [3]: df2
Out[3]:
parameter  cond  ph  temp
id
1             3   7    44
2             5   5    45
3             8   5    12
```